# Angular Material, list in sidebar not scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, material-design

I am using AngularJS, and [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org)

I want to have a [list](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/list) in a [sidebar](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav) (left), I succeeded but I cannot figure out how to set it scrollable.

Here is my code :

*sidebar.html*

```
<div ng-controller="SideBarCtrl as sideBarCtrl">
  <md-sidenav class="site-sidenav md-sidenav-left"
  md-component-id="left"
  md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
  <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z1">
    <div flex>
      <md-content>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item layout-padding class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="day in sideBarCtrl.week" ng-click="null">
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ day }}</h3>
            </div>
            <md-divider ></md-divider>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
</md-sidenav>
</div>
```

*Router.js*

```
.when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'views/sidebar.html',
     controller: 'SideBarCtrl',
     controllerAs: 'sideBarCtrl'
   })
```

*main.css*

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

I set my CSS like that so that my main page doesn't scroll. (But even without this overflow, it doesn't work)

Do you have an idea?

**EDIT 1:**

It almost works if I add a height like that (=the list scolls, but it is crop by the 100px):

```
<md-list style="overflow: scroll; height: 100px";>
...
</md-list>
```

But when I try to do for example `height: 100%` it doesn't work, it does not even scroll.

Comment: Try adding a height and overflow: scroll;

Answer (score -2):

it should have a fixed height and set overflow to scroll.

Comment: fixed height, but how much?

Comment: depends on your layout. for example 300px.

Comment: and remember to put css depending on the screen size 

Comment: And what if I want 100%?